# CSS <div> strange top padding

Tags: html, css

Im new to web development and currently developing a webapp for my mothers company.
I'm stuck on writing text block above the background image and I'm getting strange top padding in the div. I can't figure out where that comes from so I can remove it and work from there, adding additional padding and applying more css to the .text-block.

Talking about this one:

[image: strange top padding]

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var sticky = $('.main-banner'),
    scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: cursive, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main-banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #51ad89;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px grey;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #ccdbd5;
  margin: 0px 80px 0px 80px;
}

.main-nav a:hover {
  /*text-decoration: underline;*/
  color: #e6f0ec;
}

.main-nav img {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-div img {
  width: 100%;
}

.main-div {
  position: relative;
}

.text-block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.678);
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="main-banner" id="stickyHeader">
  <nav class="main-nav">
    <a href="">О студии</a>
    <a href="">Услуги</a>
    <img src="/src/tree.png" height="60px" width="60px">
    <a href="">Работы</a>
    <a href="">Контакты</a>
  </nav>
</header>
<section class="main-div">
  <img src="/src/mainphoto.png">
  <div class="text-block">
    <p>СТУДИЯ «GREEN ERA»</p>
    <p>АВТОРСКИЙ ЛАНДШАФТНЫЙ ДИЗАЙН</p>
    <button>Консультация дизайнера</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It might be the default `margin` of `p`. If you're using Chrome you can inspect and see if the space has orange-ish background (`margin`) or blue-ish (`padding`) or nothing so it can be `line-height` or something completely different

Comment: You're right! It is default margin of `<p>` and `<button>` does not have margin by default, so I was very confused of what is actually going on in the code.

Comment: You can look into reset css to remove all these default padding/margins

Comment: In general `p` element or title elements such as `h1` have some default margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the margin on the top to 0 for your `<p>` elements;

```
p {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of <p> tag's default margin [see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkUhT.png).
Use a <span> or <div> instead.